# What is the most pejorative phrase we can come up with for soccer foul fakers?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, pejorative-language

You know the ones: association football player flailing on the ground in world-class screaming agony; yet the TV replay shows he was not even touched – and it's an Oscar performance bid.  60 seconds later he's up and running full speed and as effective as ever.

What is a phrase that captures the magnitude of the shamelessness and pathetic nature of this phenomenon?

Is there a phrase you know of that stands out as perfectly descriptive of this?

“Chutzpah” comes to mind.

Comment: This is not a language-orientated response, but I'd like to see retrospective booking or even red-carding for these miraculously cured simulators.

Comment: In hockey the verb is to dive and those who do it are divers

Comment: @Kate: Used in soccer/football also. (See: [Diving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diving_%28association_football%29))

Comment: @Kate: My understanding is Italians are the real past masters at this on the football pitch, so perhaps we should raid their vocabulary and go for ***divas***.

Comment: What is funny is how slow motion replays have affected games where the all-time greats, were probably also great floppers.  Basketball players are horrible in the US.  Not only do they start falling before (fake) contact but they are cringing way too much too.  It is funny to see a guy going up for a layup and then the guy in front slowly falling down while a few inches away.

Comment: And there needs to be a new term for the affected body part (and sometimes differing from where there might have been actual contact) that was (fake) hit and then squeezed in pain by the faker.  Of course it is fine a minute later...

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm liking it.  A _"foul diva"_ is the ..front-runner so far.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers In France they call it *le cinema*. But the reason we notice it at the time of the World Cup is that, in normal league football in Britain, it is seen far less. Whilst 'diving' (pretending to be fouled) is commonplace in the Premier League, the rolling on the floor in agony, when there is no agony, I would suggest is non-existent. And I agree that the Italians and Argentinians are past-masters at it. But having said that, they have produced some wonderful football teams.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The Peruvians were at it in tonight's match at Wembley. I didn't notice a single instance from an England player. To some extent it is a function of a different style of play. The British game depends on speed, work-rate, and sheer physicality, whilst the Latin game is much more based around ball skills, strategies etc. English players expect to take knocks.

Comment: @WS2: You obviously know your football. My father (also particularly interested in the game at the *international* level) made the very same point to me not so long ago, when I was watching a game with him and complaining about Johnny Foreigner taking advantage of the fact that our players were more "gentlemanly".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think that is a word I would employ in the context. Players like John Terry, Ashley Cole, Wayne Rooney, Gary Neville, etc are not exactly models of gentility. But neither do they waste time writhing about in spurious agony, perhaps because the English game, historically, has a more macho audience which would soon ridicule such theatre. Also it is less fun writhing around in mud, in temperatures of 3 or 4 degrees, than in 30 degrees heat on a bone-dry pitch.

Comment: @WS2: Yeah - I'm no expert, but I definitely remember being cheered on that recent game by the way Rooney seemed to just bulldoze his way through sometimes. It was a bit like watching my son first learning to walk - sometimes he tripped over obstacles, and sometimes he knocked them aside - but *he never went around them*.

Comment: [Probable duplicate](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common term is **flopper** because they are flopping around like a fish.

You can also say that they are [milking it](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=milking%20it).

I would say look at that guy flopping and flailing around like an idiot.

What a *bull-shit artist* (faker/dumbass).

And someone who is really obvious would be a [ham (or hamming it up).](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/ham)

> a bad actor who has an artificial style of performing

Comment: +1 for flopper. Didn't it start with basketball? Hmm this can be an origin/etymology question also. You might add _diver_  to the answer as well.

Comment: @ermanen - flopper has been used in sports a while.  Maybe you should ask it.  Someone would have to skewer newspaper feeds probably.  Sounds Mark Twainish to me but I am sure it is older.

Comment: I was looking for something a bit more caustic, but this reminds me of the European Vlade Divac (_”Floppy Dee-vats”_) who imported that soccer style of fake foul to the Los Angeles Lakers basketball team some time ago.  He would flop on the ground and give this huge performance and everyone in the stadium, players and referees alike, would just look down at him perplexed, like: _~“What on earth are you doing son?  This isn't soccer.”~_

Comment: @ipso: So the term emerged in soccer and then it is adopted in basketball? I might ask a question about the origin of the term, you can answer if you know the details.

Comment: I coached a 6th grader who was an average basketball player (well average on AAU team) but a master of getting the charge call.  His team nickname was Floppy McFlopster or just Mcf in front of the refs.

Comment: According to the commentators for the 2014 FIFA World Cup it is called 'diving' and this practice was referred to in the game between US and Portugal